# Managing large quantity of files between two systems

Tags: git-annex

We have a large repository of files that we want to keep in sync between one central location and multiple remote locations. Currently, this is being done using rsync, but it's a slow process mainly because of how long it takes to determine the changes.

My current thought is to find a VCS-like solution where instead of having to check all of the files, we can check the diffs between revisions to determine what gets sent over the wire. My biggest concern, however, is that we'd have to re-sync all of the files that are currently in-sync, which is a significant effort. I've been told that the current repository is about .5 TB and consists of a variety of files of different sizes. I understand that an initial commit will most likely take a significant amount of time, but I'd rather avoid the syncing between clusters if possible.

One thing I did look at briefly is git-annex, but my first concern is that it may not like dealing with thousands of files. Also, one thing I didn't see is what would happen if the file already exists on both systems. If I create a repo using git-annex on the central system and then set up repos on the remote clusters, will pushing from central to a remote repo cause it to sync all of the files?

If anyone has alternative solutions/ideas, I'd love to see them.

Thanks.